# Accessing less properties

Tags: css, less

I'm sorry, I think it's already been asked, but I don't know which keywords I should use, as I'm new to less.

I need to do something like :

```
.class1 {
    top: 10%;
    height: 20%
 }
 .class2 {
    top: .class1->top + .class1->height + 10%;
    height: class1->height;
 }
```

Is it possible to do this without defining variables such as @class1top and @class1height ?

Thanks for answers, or a redirection to this question if you can find one

Have a good day :)

Comment: No you can't directly access the property values of another class like that. You would have to use variables.

Comment: Not possible now. Its a feature request, you can join the discussion here https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2433